# How to set the color for the Discord embed in my HTML website?

Tags: html, discord

I'm currently developing a website for my Discord bot and wanted to know how to set the color for the embed in HTML.

When I post my url on Discord, an embed comes up but without color. How can I change it?

With `<meta name="theme-color" content="color">` it does not work.

Comment: Put more code in snippet so we guide you easily

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible. Have you found any links where the color is not the default?

Comment: It does work with the code, Discord just takes a very, very long time to apply the change, and yes in fact it is possible to change the color. sorrryy <3

Answer (score 7):

i found that putting `<meta name="theme-color" content="#00aa00">` at the top of my meta info worked

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else wondering, this is the correct way to do it, and the changes should take place as soon it propagates. The issue is that Discord caches website embeds. To force the embed to update locally, the quickest method is to append an empty fragment to your URL when posting it to Discord.

For example, if the link `http://example.com/` is still showing the old embed, try reposting/editing the link as `http://example.com/#`. Since the URL is different, Discord will not pull from the same cache. *This method also has the advantage of forcing an update for anyone else that'd cached the original embed before it was changed on your website.* You can append additional fragments to the URL, as many times as needed: `http://example.com/#####`

Alternatively, you can clear Discord's cache by opening the Chromium dev tools (`ctrl` + `i`), clearing the cache, and then reloading (`ctrl` + `shift` + `r`). *This method will only update the embed for yourself, though if nobody else saw the original embed before it was changed on your website, Discord will show them the latest content.*

Comment: Thank you, added the # and it worked on discord.